# TCP Socket Transfer

Tags: sockets, tcp, packet

A while back i had a question about why my socket sometimes received only 653 octets ( for example ) when i sent 1024 octets and thanks to Rakis i understood: The OS allows reception to occur in arbitrarily sized chunks.

This time i need a confirmation :)

On any OS ( Well GNU/Linux and Windows at least ), In any Language ( I'm using Python here ), if i send a packet of a random number of bytes, can be 2 bytes, can be 12000 bytes, let's say X, when i write socket.send(X), am i absolutely guaranteed that X will be FULLY received ( regardless of any chunks the receiving OS divides it into ) on the other end of the socket BEFORE i do another socket.send(any string) ?

Or in other words if i have the code :

```
socket.send(X)
socket.send(Y)
```

Even if X > MTU so it will be obliged to send multiple packets, does it wait until every packet is sent and acknowledged by the endpoint of the socket before sending Y ? Well writing that makes me believe that the answer is yes it is guaranteed and that this is exactly the purpose of setting a socket in blocking mode but i want to be sure :D

Thanks in advance,
Nolhian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are guaranteed that X will be *received* (at the application level) before Y, if it's a stream socket. If it's a datagram socket, no guarantees.

Depending on the networking implementation, it's possible that at a lower level, X will be sent, lost in transmission, then Y will be sent, then X will be re-sent because no acknowledgement was received.

Even in blocking mode, the socket.send(Y) can execute before X even makes it "onto the wire", because the OS will buffer network traffic.

Comment: Thanks that's what i needed to know, that my application will always receive X before Y no matter what with a TCP socket. If i understand correctly even if the OS receives Y before X ( due to lost/resending ), it will buffer it and wait to receive X to finally forward X and Y in the correct order to the application ? I guess that's part of the TCP procotol ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

All you know is that the client will receive the data in order, assuming it *does* receive it all. There's no way of knowing (at the application level) whether the client has received all the data without having some sort of "ACK" at the application level protocol.

Comment: Hello, first thanks for your answer but i'm confused. The TCP protocol is supposed to guarantee that all the data is received and in correct order, so why the italic style does ? On the application level as you say it is not possible to know, but in reality even if the application can't know, that's the job of TCP to make sure it does receive all the data or am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Nolhian: If the network dies before all the data has actually made it to the other end, there's not a lot that TCP can do about that. When the connection has timed out, a Send will fail after that... but until that point, it won't.

Comment: Indeed, didn't think you meant an interrupted connection ! It won't be that important in my case because the only thing that matters is that the client never receives data in the wrong order but thanks for pointing that out ! The most important thing is, as you confirmed it, the client will always receive the data in order, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

> am i absolutely guaranteed that X will be FULLY received ( regardless of any chunks the receiving OS divides it into ) on the other end of the socket BEFORE i do another socket.send(any string) ?

No.  In general, more data may be sent without waiting for the receiving side, within certain limits:

- on the sending side, you will have a maximum amount of data you can enqueue for transmission until the client has acknowledged some receipt (but typically the client's OS will acknowledge and buffer quite a lot before it refuses further data until the application has processed some), after which the sending socket may start blocking

  - forces the application design to consider how to enqueue and buffer excessive amounts of data, rather than having naively written applications utilise excessive amounts of Operating System-provided buffer memory
  - reduces retransmission rates when the receiving side is flooded with data too fast to process it
  - avoids sending huge amounts of data despite the network connection having been lost

So, strictly speaking and for large transmissions, the sender should be designed to handle sockets blocked from further sends (either knowing it is ok to block in the attempt (perhaps due to a dedicated sending thread) or waiting until it is possible to send more via non-blocking sockets or select/poll).

*Whatever retransmission and buffering may be required, what you CAN be sure of is that the receiving side will have to read all of "X" before it starts being given the subsequently sent data "Y" (unless it specifically asks to have it otherwise, e.g. Out Of Band data).*

Comment: Thanks for this really technical explanation and the ideas in the last but one paragraph ! Also the last paragraph confirms the answer of Russell Borogove and Jon Skeet !

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the [type of Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket#Socket_types) that you use, you can, in some cases, have a guarantee that data will be received, but not a feedback or a confirmation when it actually was.

---

**Back to your question:**

> does it wait until every packet is **sent** and **acknowledged** by the endpoint of the socket before sending Y

So, you could say:

- YES it does wait until it is sent, and
- NO it does not wait for acknowledgment

---

**A suggestion:**

Since there are **no auto-magic/built-in confirmations** that your data was received, you could fairly easily **implement your own logic** for `ACK`nowledging the package was received, which would basically come down to your *custom communication protocol*.

Comment: No and no. It doesn't wait for it to be sent and it doesn't wait for an acknowledgement.